# How do I remove Android 11 Cat easter egg when I have Android 12?

Tags: android-11, android-12, easter-egg, samsung-one-ui

After updating my Samsung phone to Android 12 I wanted to remove the Android 11 easter egg, but since I have Android 12 now I can't do it. Does anyone know how to fix this (apart from factory reset)?

Comment: The question is why? The easter egg(s) are part of the system so "uninstalling" (effectively disabling) them has no advantage as they reside on the read-only system partition.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that, since those Easter eggs are part of the system, and not an app you can install/uninstall as you wish. I think the best you could do is to report a bug to Google saying the old Easter egg wasn't removed when you updated to Android 12 - maybe they'll fix it and release in a system update (however, I'll hardly believe they will spend time fixing such small thing).

Answer (score 0):

Find out the package name for the easter egg (which will be something like "*com.android.egg*") using something like this:[App Inspector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubqsoft.sec01).
Then you can proceed to uninstall the app follwing this [guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/),connecting the phone to a PC through adb(Android Debug bridge) and using the command:

"*adb shell pm uninstall --user 0* ".

Though in case of system apps it is pretty much just disabling it: they will be back on a factory reset or you can even choose to reinstall it using the "*abd shell cmd package install-existing* "** command.

You can use this method to remove any useless system apps which can't be uninstalled from inside the phone's menu.

*install adb from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#downloads).
**replace <package name> with the appropriate pacakge name.